# How to display a list of the top used taxonomy terms and the recent nodes submitted to them?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Im on d7. Im trying to make a page on my site that displays the top 5 most used taxonomy terms and the most recent nodes that have been tagged with them. Something like this:

```
    ---Term a---
      ---Node 1 (title)---
      ---Node 1 (byline)---
      ---Node 1 (teaser)---

      ---Node 2 (title)---
      ---Node 2 (byline)---
      ---Node 2 (teaser)---

      ---Node 3 (title)---
      ---Node 3 (byline)---
      ---Node 3 (teaser)---

    ---Term b---
      ---Node 1 (title)---
      ---Node 1 (byline)---
      ---Node 1 (teaser)---

      ---Node 2 (title)---
      ---Node 2 (byline)---
      ---Node 2 (teaser)---

      ---Node 3 (title)---
      ---Node 3 (byline)---
      ---Node 3 (teaser)---

   ---Term c---
      ---Node 1 (title)---
      ---Node 1 (byline)---
      ---Node 1 (teaser)---

      ---Node 2 (title)---
      ---Node 2 (byline)---
      ---Node 2 (teaser)---

      ---Node 3 (title)---
      ---Node 3 (byline)---
      ---Node 3 (teaser)---

      ---ETC---
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?